# Connect to wireless network

Tags: powershell, wireless

I have created a couple of PowerShell scripts which configure computers used in a training class.  Some classes need to connect to a different wireless network (SSID).  I can just instruct users how to use the windows XP facilitites to change the network they are connected to but I would like to be able to roll the network selection in to my PowerShell script
Any idea on how to change wireless network in PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find this project interesting. It is just a .NET wrapper on the native API. You should be able to call this from PowerShell without too much trouble:

http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/

Comment: how did u connect it ..? Im getting  an error  the parameter is incorrect