# How do I get Python to know what Wifi the user is connected to?

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, wifi

I'm 14, pardon my Python knowlege.  I'm trying to make this program that will only run while I'm at school (on the school's Wifi) using an if/else statement like this:

```
if ontheschoolwifi:
     Keep running the program
else:
     close the program because im not at school and wont need it
```

I'd like to know how to let python know how to get what wifi it is connected to.
Thank you, in advance, for your help :)

Comment: Which operating system? Programming languages are just languages, but wifi is a hardware interface which is generally handled by the operating system and _very loosely speaking_, the OS is responsible for exposing an application programming interface (API) which programs, written in a language (say Python) can use to query/interact with.

Comment: @metatoaster Im running Windows 10.

Comment: Take a look at this thread and its linked threads: [Associating my Windows computer to a wifi AP with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077835/associating-my-windows-computer-to-a-wifi-ap-with-python)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import subprocess

if "SchoolWifiName" in subprocess.check_output("netsh wlan show interfaces"):
    print "I am on school wifi!"
```

Answer (score 10):

here some code that actually works, the other answers did not work for me on Windows...

```
import subprocess

wifi = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'WLAN', 'show', 'interfaces'])
data = wifi.decode('utf-8')
if "school_wifi_name" in data:
    print("connected to speccific wifi")
else:
    print("not connected")
```

Answer (score 6):

For Mac OS query the airport using `os` module.
`"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I"`
Then, look the name assigned to `SSID` by your school.
It should be something similar for the other operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

This will help you out to get the network name.

```
import subprocess

subprocess_result = subprocess.Popen('iwgetid',shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess_output = subprocess_result.communicate()[0],subprocess_result.returncode
network_name = subprocess_output[0].decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be the best solution:

```
import subprocess

if 'SchoolWifiName' in subprocess.check_output("netsh wlan show interfaces").decode('utf-8'):
    print('I am on school wifi!')
```

Comment: This is the same, essentially, as the current top answer, except adapted for Python 3.

Comment: @DominikStańczak0 That's right we live in 2022.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

print(str(subprocess.check_output(['iwgetid -r'], shell=True)).split('\'')[1][:-2])
```

will print the current Wi-Fi SSID

To check if the SSID has the desired name:

```
import subprocess

if 'School_wifi_name' in str(subprocess.check_output(['iwgetid -r'], shell=True)).split('\'')[1][:-2]:
  print('I am on school Wi-Fi!')
```