# How to get Network name with python

Tags: python, networking

Does anyone know how to get this "Network 3" with python?

[image]

Comment: Good question. -

Comment: Not the most pythonic, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227160/how-do-i-get-python-to-know-what-wifi-the-user-is-connected-to could be what you're looking for. Or check https://pypi.org/project/python-wifi/ which came up on the first page of a web search.