# Check the network name using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, internet-explorer, wifi

In a computer (with windows 10 OS), there are many networks available as shown below (ref: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-connect-hidden-wireless-networks-windows-10/):

[image]

Now lets say, if I am connected to network "adriano", then is there any way by which I can get this information using python ?

Can anyone please help me out with this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get Python to know what Wifi the user is connected to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227160/how-do-i-get-python-to-know-what-wifi-the-user-is-connected-to)

Comment: Thanks a lot @RJAdriaansen
This has solved my query!

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
import subprocess

def get_ssid():
    raw_wifi = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'WLAN', 'show', 'interfaces'])
    data_strings = raw_wifi.decode('utf-8').split()
    index = data_strings.index('Profile')
    return data_strings[index + 2]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).