# How to view the parameters of a connected wi-fi network in python

Tags: windows, networking, wifi

I need the program to display what parameters the connected wifi network has. For example, protocol, encryption, SSID, etc. And gow to get network`s strength? On windows 11

Actually I didn't find such information for python

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227160/how-do-i-get-python-to-know-what-wifi-the-user-is-connected-to) might help.