# Log in to wifi using python

Tags: python, windows

I have checked other posts but they don't seem to answer the question. The thing is i have a password and name of wifi and want to connect, is there a way to do this? Tried cmd and it doesnt seem to have an option to do that. I'm working on windows.

Comment: Did you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077835/associating-my-windows-computer-to-a-wifi-ap-with-python/14079546#14079546 ?

Comment: Yes I did, and that's not what I'm looking for. It only works for remembered wifi's. I want to connect to a new one. But thanks for help:)